# Html Paragraph styling: making it like this

Tags: html, css

how can I make a paragraph format look like this

[image]

using this code?
Thank you! :)

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-lg-7 sec-about-text">
  <p> Healthy Endings came to life with the best intentions to create all natural snacks, organic when possible, raw and vegan with absolutely no preservatives. We love to snack periodically through out the day and we're always working on creating the most delicious and nutritious snacks to satisfy those cravings.  "What fun is snacking if the snacks donít taste orgasmically good!"</p>
  <p> Cherie Spencer, the founder and creator
    of Healthy Endings snacks received her
    certification as a Health Educator from
    the world renowned Hippocrates Health
    Institute in West Palm Beach, Florida and holds a Bachelors in Healthcare Administration from Florida Atlantic University. She also received a culinary certification from Atlantic County VoTech and holds a SafeServ Food Manager Certification/License. She is a holistic chef specializing in raw, living foods and loves to prepare and share healthy food with family and friends.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a jsfiddle showing the basic process: https://jsfiddle.net/jq16sfjg/

```
.floated {
  margin: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

I will leave it up to you to style the font, whitespace, and colors.

Basically, you just need to float the text that breaks the paragraph to the right.